# Pass arguments to App object in Scala

Tags: scala, testing

I am currently creating with scalatest.org some unit tests for my application:

```
scala> object Test extends App {
     | println(args)
     | }
```

How can I pass parameters to that object? I tried overriding the `args` value but after some research I discovered that it is not possible:

```
  /** The command line arguments passed to the application's `main` method.
   */
  @deprecatedOverriding("args should not be overridden", "2.11.0")
  protected def args: Array[String] = _args

  private var _args: Array[String] = _
```

How can I pass to the underscore `_` custom parameters in the code?

Cheers

Comment: It seems like a code smell to me to be fixated on the App as the entry point for injecting new data. Why not run this from the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want to invoke the `main(args: Array[String])` method inherited from App.

```
scala> object Test extends App { args.foreach(println) }
defined object Test

scala> Test.main(Array("A1"))
A1

scala> Test.main(Array("A1", "A2"))
A1
A2
```

Comment: `val test = Test; test.main(Array("test"))` very well that worked for me, thanks!